# Compile Error in Hidden Module: Module 1

Tags: vba, excel, ribbonx

I've an Addin for Excel-2010 in VBA.  If I execute the code from the VBA editor it works fine.  But when I execute the macro using the button in the Ribbon generated for the Addin it throws this error: `Compile Error in Hidden Module: Module 1`

**My code:**

```
Sub QE_eventhandler(control As IRibbonControl)
    If MsgBox("Esta acción no se podrá deshacer. ¿Desea Continuar?", vbExclamation + vbOKCancel, "Confirmar -Quitar Espacios-") = vbOK Then
        QuitaEspacios
    End If
End

Sub QuitaEspacios()
Dim celda As Range
    For Each celda In Selection
        If TypeName(celda.Value) = "String" Then
            celda.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Trim(celda.Value)
        End If
    Next
 End Sub
```

**The code generated with the Custom UI Editor:**

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui">
    <ribbon>
        <tabs>
            <tab id="customTab" label="GARSA Tools">
                <group id="customGroup1" label="Reformateo Texto">
                    <button id="customButton3" label="Quitar Espacios" size="large" onAction="QE_eventhandler" imageMso="TextEffectTracking" />
                </group>
            </tab>
        </tabs>
    </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing an `End Sub` at the end of the callback - you just have `End`:

```
Sub QE_eventhandler(control As IRibbonControl)
    If MsgBox("Esta acción no se podrá deshacer. ¿Desea Continuar?", vbExclamation + vbOKCancel, "Confirmar -Quitar Espacios-") = vbOK Then
        QuitaEspacios
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev No, it isn't. All routines must end in `End Sub`, not `End`.

Comment: Yes, you are right - [Sub Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278504.aspx). There is a difference between Visual Basic and VBA.

Comment: That was the issue.  Thanks a lot @Rory !!

Answer (score 0):

Check out the following links which describe a similar issue:

[You receive a "Compile error in hidden module" error message when you start Word or Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/307410?wa=wsignin1.0)

[compile error in Excel](http://www.codedawn.com/index/-compile-error-in-hidden-module-message-in-excel)